# I can't convert with ImageMagick

Tags: php, centos, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick to convert a PDF file.

I use this PHP snippet:

```
$cadena = "/usr/local/bin/convert -density 100 -colorspace rgb ".$name_path." ".$images_path."/convert.png";
shell_exec($cadena);
```

where `$name_path` is the PDF file directory and `$images_path` is the images directory.

This code in console (CentOS)  works perfectly. But when I try to use `shell_exec()` function in PHP it throws this error:

```
***warning: considering '00000000 xxxxx n' as free entry.
*** this file had erros thah were repaired  or ignored.
```

The permissions in file and folders are 777.
I don't know why. Can somebody help me?

Comment: that's not a permissions error. the pdf contains stuff that imagick doesn't know about (or more likely, ghostscript doesn't know about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, two observations:

1. The message you see is not from ImageMagick, it is from Ghostscript.
2. The message is not an *error* message, but merely a *warning*.

So it may well be that your conversion did work and you'll have the desired output in `$image_path`. Did you check?

Then, three more points:

1. ImageMagick does not and can not process input PDF itself. It employs Ghostscript as its *delegate* to convert PDF to an image format first, which is then taken over by ImageMagick for further processing.
2. It is not necessarily the case that the Ghostscript version you executed in the CentOS console is the same as the one which is executed by your PHP `shell_exec`. You should check that for both instances. The console command to do this is `gs -version`. If you have different versions, this would explain why you do see the warning message in one instance, but not in the other.
3. You could add `-verbose` to your commands (`shell_exec` as well as in console) to see which instance of Ghostscript the IM `convert` command invokes "behind your back"....

Comment: I checked and I have two versions of ghostscript in my server. I wrote  gs - version in the console and show me this:
GPL Ghostscript 9.16 (2015-03-30)

 Then I did a script with shell_exec() and show me  GPL Ghostscript 8.70 (2009-07-31). What can i do to remove the old version  (8.7) or shell_exec() works with last one?

Comment: sorry I'm new. I'm going to do that. 
Thank you

Comment: @KarlitozParkerHimura: Thx. I hope your problem gets resolved soon then. Don't forget to describe precisely how you identified your two GS versions and which they are. Also interesting might be the PHP version and the CentOS version you are using.